# Is it possible to change this div color on scroll using purely CSS?

Tags: html, css, sass

Thanks for taking the time to read my post.
So I've started freelancing recently (CSS and HTML) and I've found my first difficulty.

[image: First example image]

Look at the green bar (Its a fixed div), its green for testing porpuses, but client wants it to be transparent when on top of this orange background...

[image: second example image]

...But switch to another color when on top of this white background (So the letters can be seen)

Is this possible to do with CSS? If so, how do I do it?
Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Pure css does not currently have any amount of responsiveness to what is and is not onscreen.  So, the short lame answer is "not with just css."

That being said, it's very easy to do this with js.

The event you'll be looking for is [`scroll` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event).

From there you can add/remove a class for styling.

Something like this:

```
// wait for document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded");

const myHeader = document.getElementById("MyHeader");
window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
  const scrollPos = window.scrollY;
  if (scrollPos ... add your logic here) {
    myHeader.classList.add("scrollIsThing");  // this is the css class you'll target
  } else {
    myHeader.classList.remove("scrollIsThing");
  }
});
```

Sorry there's no good css way to do this.

Comment: Thank you for your help! This worked for me

Edit: Whoops, just realized code doesn't look very good in comments.
Here's a codepen link for anyone that may have the same doubt I had. Thanks Seph Reed!

https://codepen.io/jorge-romero/pen/WWXbVY

Answer (score 0):

It is "kind of" possible to do this just with css if you can accept some html markup duplication. You can split the fixed header into two layers, one for white text, one for background, and using `z-index` you can sandwich the content between these two header layers (in case of a colorful content), in which case only the white text would be visible, and position the white content below the header background. A sample of such behavior is shown below:

```css
.header {
  height: 50px;
  background: transparent;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  font-family: sans;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 50px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.header.header-background {
  background: teal;
  z-index: 1;
}

.body1 {
  height: 120vh;
  background: orange;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
}

.body2 {
  height: 120vh;
  background: #eee;
  
}

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  White text
</div>
<div class="body1"></div>
<div class="header header-background">

</div>
<div class="body2"></div>
```