# Smooth transition of background-color

Tags: javascript, css, background, transition, background-color

I have a problem with the color transition on my site.

Basically, I want to transition from a black background-color to white but I want it to go like on this site https://bullmade.dk/ - smooth (check the inspect when you scroll or the video below).
https://streamable.com/w3uso2

I tried it like this but it doesn't work smoothly on mobile...

```css
body {
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    transition: background-color .3s linear;
  will-change: background-color;
}
```

I really appreciate any help you can provide.

Comment: Is this a mobile-only question?

Comment: FYI: The CSS transition property is standard and has been for several years now. Vendor prefixes are not needed.

Comment: @ScottMarcus But will it on old browers? Say from 5 years ago or more?

Comment: Please could you put a runnable snippet into your question so we can see the problem for ourselves? See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example for help with doing this.

Comment: check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55669561/is-it-possible-to-change-this-div-color-on-scroll-using-purely-css) they are suggesting that it is not possible to approach onScroll with pure CSS, you need some Javascript + CSS to do that :)

Comment: CSS 3 was standardized over 5 years ago. Vendor prefixes aren’t meant to be in use forever.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my code, but it's not working smoothly like on the example it just changes from black to white not step by step and I get some lag on mobile.

I got elementor sections with `data-color attribute` I use CSS body and JS to make the transition based on scroll position.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function( jQuery ) {
    jQuery(window).on('scroll touchmove', function() {

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() >= jQuery('#one').position().top) {
            jQuery('body').css('background-color', jQuery('#one').attr('data-color'));
        }

        if (jQuery(document).scrollTop() > jQuery('#two').position().top-50) {
            jQuery('body').css('background-color', jQuery('#two').attr('data-color'));
        }

    });
})
```

```css
body {
  background-color:rgb(0,0,0);
  -webkit-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background-color .3s linear;
    transition: background-color .3s linear;
  will-change: background-color;
}
h1
{
font-family:'Arial', sans-serif;
font-weight:800;
font-size:35px;
}
section
{
  height:100vh;
  color:#fff;
  margin: auto;
  width:100%;
  text-align:center;
}
section h1
{
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
#two h1
{
color:#000;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="one" data-color="rgb(0,0,0)">
<h1>Example</h1>
</section>
<section id="two" data-color="rgb(255,255,255)">
<h1>Example</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this maybe?

```css
body {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0);
  animation: backgroundFade .3s;
}

@keyframes backgroundFade {
  0%   {background-color: rgba(255,255,255);}
  100%   {background-color: rgba(0,0,0);}
}
```

```html
<body></body>
```

Comment: Might work but how can i implement animation in my case.
I need to have the color changed by the JS, basically, JS code needs to check what data attributes the HTML element holds and change the color to that attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was GSAP ScrollTrigger, and here is how

```js
gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);

gsap.utils.toArray('.section').forEach((section, i) => {
  
  if(section.getAttribute('data-color') !== null) {
    
    var colorAttr = section.getAttribute('data-color')
    
    gsap.to('body', {
      backgroundColor: colorAttr === "dark" ? gsap.getProperty("html", "--dark") : gsap.getProperty("html", "--light"),
      immediateRender: false,
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: section,
        scrub: true,
        start:'top bottom',
        end: '+=100%'
      }
    });

  }
  
});
```

```css
:root {
    --light: #fff;
    --dark: #000;
}

body{
  background:var(--dark);
}
section
{
height:100vh;
text-align:center;
padding:50px;
}
.txt-1
{
color:#fff;
}
.txt-2
{
color:#000;
}
```

```html
<section class="section" data-color="dark">
<h1 class="txt-1">EXAMPLE</h1>
</section>
<section class="section" data-color="light">
<h1 class="txt-2">EXAMPLE</h1>
</section>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/gsap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/3.9.1/ScrollTrigger.min.js"></script>
```